# First servlet, but not able to open it

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

Actually i try to create my first servlet and open it in a browser. But i alway get a 404 error.

My webapps folder from tomcat directory looks like:

```
docs
examples
host-manageR
manager
ROOT
test
    index.htmL

    servlet
        bin
            test.class
        src
            test.java
    .classpath
    .project

    WEB-INF
        classes
```

my index.html:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div style="width:500px;height:300px;margin:auto;background-color:#EEEEEE;padding:0px 10px 0px 10px;margin-top:50px;">
        <h1>Send Text</h1>
        <form action="servlet/bin/test" method="get" style="font-size:10px;">
            <textarea rows="10" cols="59" name="input"></textarea>
            <input type="submit" style="margin-top:20px;"></input>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

and this is my test class:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.*; 

@WebServlet(urlPatterns={"/servlet/bin/test"})
public class test extends HttpServlet{

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException,IOException{
        PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
        res.setContentType("text/html");
        out.println("this is First servlet Example ");
    }
}
```

I know it does nothing with the input from the html form but at this point I just want to open it and see the text inside^^... But when i open:

```
http://localhost:8080/test/index.html
```

, fill in the form and countinue or when i open:

```
http://localhost:8080/test/servlet/bin/test
```

directly, i always get a 404 error with everything i tried. I would prefer a solution without a xml but i think the problem is not there.

Comment: The class file needs to be in the `classes` directory

Comment: And how should the paths look like. I mean in the class file and what should i open to open the servlet.

I don't think it's /WEB-INF/classes/test right?

Comment: Yup, the 2nd url looks good, it should work when you copy the class file into `classes`

Comment: Well now i get this: "The requested resource () is not available.". I moved the test.class file into the classes folder and opened http://localhost:8080/test/WEB-INF/classes/test

Comment: Try within your jsp response.encodeURL(/bin/serlvet/test) or response.encodeRedirectURL("") with in your form action. Maybe it can't resolve the current context path

Comment: your servlet class must be located under WEB-INF/classes/<your-servlet>

Comment: with the first one I get:
"The requested resource (/test/response.encodeURL(/servlet/bin/test)) is not available."
and with the second one I get:
The requested resource (/test/response.encodeRedirectURL(%27/servlet/bin/test%27)) is not available.

Comment: @ Christian Schack it is now but it also don't work

Comment: Are you sure that the deployment is correct. Check server log after deploying you war-file. The server logs out any kind of information  of the servlet registration within the container

Comment: Be sure that under the classes folder the directory structur applies to the package definition of your servlet.

Comment: I edited your question for a reason-so it fits SO question guidelines better. If you're going to edit it, edit in quality content, not fluff and starred-out curse words.

Comment: I think you need a web.xml that at least specifies a webapp name and the webapp version (3.0 if you want to use annotations to find servlets)

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems in this code.

You're not respecting Java naming conventions. Classes should always start with an uppercase letter. They should never be in the default package.

You're deploying your whole development environment (sources, etc.), instead of generating a correct war file or exploded war file, and to deply that. The structure of your web-app should be

```
test
    any static file you want
    WEB-INF
        classes
            .class files, organized in directories strictly matching the package hierarchy
        lib
            jar files needed by your application
```

You're confused about what

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns={"/servlet/bin/test"})
```

does. The url patterns is the set of URLs that you would like to use to access your servlet. The value doesn't have anything to do with the actual location of the servlet class on the disk. If you want the URL of your servlet to be `/hello`, then you simply use

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns={"/hello"})
```

or, even simpler:

```
@WebServlet("/hello")
```

Once deployed, the complete URL of the servlet will thus be:

```
http://localhost:8080/test/hello
```

`/test` being the context path your webapp which is, by default, the name of the war file of exploded war directory you put under tomcat/webapps.

Comment: thx very much i will give this a try now. Bu i never heard about "war"

Comment: now i cannot compile the java file anymore. Eclipse give me a Joice to run it as application or applet but not as servlet sience i changed the class name

Comment: @user1665154: if you've never heard the term "war" and are developing web applications, then it means you've never read any tutorial about Java web apps. You should. What did you change in the code, and what the compilation error message: that would tell you what the problem is. Moreover, if you run it from Eclipse, then you shouldn't have anything inside tomcat's wabappas folder. Eclipse will create the appopriate structure and deploy the application for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow these tutorials in [Java-Brains](http://javabrains.koushik.org/p/contents.html) for JSP & Servlets its very simple and explain every things from scratch :)

Comment: Links to big big big tutorials and books are always bad ;) to big to find something specific and to big for the time i have for just some little things.

Comment: It was an advice to follow these tutorials but if you need to find your problem solution see JSPs and Servlets Tutorial 01 - Setting up @ 7:03

Answer (score 0):

I think after all the comments the problem is just that your
web archive is not even registered within the server.

Try to package everthing under test as a zip file and rename it to test.war.
A war file is nothing more as a zip file with ending "war" for web archive
which indicates that server should resolve the archive as a web application.

if you extract this archive it should look like this.

```
index.html
WEB-INF
   web.xml
     |- classes
          |- test.class   
     |- lib
```

Deploy this file using the management console of tomcat and manually deploy it to your server.

Additionally have a look about Webarchives "war".

If the servlet is registered within the server correctly than you reach it using
the specified pattern which you declared within @WebServlet Annotation.
The context path applies to the name of you war archive.

```
http://localhost:8080/<name of the warfile>/<urlPattern>
http://localhost:8080/test/servlet/bin/test // if the given example still applies
```

Comment: The direcotry now looks like this and i opened localhost:8080/test/test (the name from the war file and the one in the anotation in the class file)

still no sucess

another question. why index.jsp is .html not possible it'sjust a form.

Comment: I just thought you had an index.jsp as entry point for your application. Of course when you just have a index.html than index.html has to be within the archive. It is also possible. Are you now sure that you webserver deployed your servlet successfully. CHeck the logs.